# Json parsing with scala/play: how to get a trait?

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I am stuck when trying to read a Json in Scala using play2, employing the information to create an object. 
This is my code right now:

```
  trait MyTrait {
  }

  object object1 extends MyTrait {
    override def toString: String = "object1"
  }

  object object2 extends MyTrait{
    override def toString: String = "object2"
  }

  def strToObject(str: String): MyTrait = str match {
    case "object1" => object1
    case "object2" => object2
  }
```

This is how i WRITE Json:

```
 implicit val traitWrites = new Writes[MyTrait] {
    def writes(t: MyTrait) = Json.obj(
      "t" -> t.toString)
  }
```

Output

```
println("object1: " + Json.toJson(object1).toString)
println("object2: " + Json.toJson(object1).toString)

object1: {"t":"object1"}
object2: {"t":"object1"}
```

This is how I'm trying to READ, but it does not work.

```
 implicit val traitReads: Reads[MyTrait] = (
    (JsPath \ " t" ).read[String])map(str => strToObject(str)) (MyTrait.apply _)

  val jsonObject = Json.parse(Json.toJson(object1).toString)
  val aux = jsonObject \ "t"
  val myobject = aux.as[MyTrait]
```

It complains about the (MyTrait.apply _) and as[MyTrait]with "not found: value MyTrait". It is however the very same thing I do with standard classes, so I don't really know how to proceed.

Any idea? I am quite a newbie with Play (and with Scala too, to be true) so probably I am doing something very basic wrong. In particular, I highly suspect of the "map" call.

Cheers,

Comment: Sealed trait are automatically supported by latest release

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Traits don't have an apply method, these are normally used with case classes.
You can extend the Reads trait and implement the reads method, like this:

```
implicit val creatureReads = new Reads[MyTrait] {
  override def reads(js: JsValue): JsResult[MyTrait] = {
    JsSuccess(strToObject((js \ "t" ).as[String]))
  }
}
```

I edited my answer to return a JsSuccess, you can add better validation to check for the existence of "t".

Also your code should be calling:

```
val myobject = jsonObject.as[MyTrait]
```